# Undefined index in post method of JSON object sent by jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've tried almost all suggestions but it doesn't work. My `id`s are working properly in the JavaScript function when I `alert` my array using `arr['id']`. However, when I try `$_POST['id']` on a different PHP file (I've used AJAX and specified the URL) is gives me an error.

scriptfile.php:

```
<script>
function detailsmodal(cid, pid) {
    var arr = { "cid": cid, "pid": pid };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/frontend/include/detailsmodal.php',
        method: "post",
        data: arr,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('body').append(data);
            jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

detailsmodal.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['cid'];
?>
```

Comment: what is the error in php?

Comment: its giving "unidentified index" as an error for cid

Comment: the question talks about "id", the code talks about "cid". And "tried it on a different PHP file"...different to what? different to the one shown here? Or this _is_ the different one? The question is a little unclear IMO. As far as I can see, what you've written here should work, assuming that your JS variables actually have values when you make the request. What is the value of "cid" when you submit the request? (You can check in your browser's network tools by looking into the request body of the ajax call)

Comment: ive passed values to cid and pid of the function and have checked the form data as well....its jst that when i use the post method using cid as an index it comes out as unidentified

Comment: why is an object called arr? :)

Comment: short for array

Comment: Did you try to dump `$_POST` and see what it spits out?

Comment: "short for array"...yes but epascarello's point was that it isn't an array, it's an object. Hence the odd choice of name.

Comment: ya sorry about that..Im new to using json and just learning over youtube at the moment for my project

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending your data as json like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/frontend/include/detailsmodal.php",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ cid: cid, pid: pid }),
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('body').append(data);
                jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("something went wrong");
            }
        });
```

For the decoding you could use javascript JSON.parse

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

or

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data["cid"];
```

Comment: that will just submit a single string. So it would need to be decoded on the server. That's fine, but you should mention it and give an example.

Comment: could you send the decoding part of it?

Comment: there is a way through php?

Comment: Its still giving me an error for cid (Unidentified index cid)

Comment: Could you please give it a try again with the new way I wrote for receiving your data....?